# Parametrize function at compile time based on user expression

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, pointer-to-member

I'm writing a C++11 library in which the user needs to specify a `struct` to use and the elements to be used (in order). For example:

```
// Declaration
struct MyData{ double x, y ,z;};
...
// Use
MyClass<MyData, y, x> myobj;
MyData mydata;
myobj.set(mydata);
...
```

Then, `MyClass` should generate different functions that iterate through the parameter pack, but considering the parameters as expressions. For that, I declared a class with a parameter pack:

```
template<class T, class ... G>
class MyClass{
    std::vector<double*> var;
    public:
    Test();
    void set(T const& var_);
 };
```

And then I can't figure out how to generate the `set()` function. The behavior should be like the following pseudo-code:

```
 template<class T, class ... G>
 void Test<T, G...>::set(T const& var_){
 unsigned pos = 0;
 for(unsigned i =0; i < sizeof...(G); i++)
     *var[i] = var_.G(i);
}
```

Which, in the case of `MyClass<MyData,y,x>` would generate:

```
...
*var[0] = var_.y;
*var[1] = var_.x;
...
```

Comment: Your example is not valid C++. Even `MyClass<MyData, y, x> myobj;` isn't going to be well-formed, so any discussion about `set` is pointless.

Comment: Could you please share why you want to accomplish? There are probably better ways to do whatever it is you want. This smells like an XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: "at compile time based on user expression" User expressions *tend* to be **runtime** phenomena

Comment: @StoryTeller Treat it as pseudocode. I'm sure you can generate code based on user defined "expression"

Comment: @CrisLuengo I need to generate setters, getters and allocate a vector that depends on a struct and the elements of the struct that the user wants to use. It is not trivial but with Metaprogramming should be achievable. I will do some research about macro to substitute the user code inside the function definition, but no success for the moment

Comment: @manucalo: yes, that is what I understood from your question. But why do you think you need this, what it is that your are really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In seems to me that your looking a way to pass a variadic sequence of pointer to member of structs/classes as template parameter and a way to use they.

The syntax to pass a variadic sequence of pointer to member of structs/classes as template parameter is the following

```
template <typename T, typename U, U T::* ... Ms>
struct MyClass
 { /* something */ };
```

but, in your case, you've fixed the `U` type as `double` so you can simplify as follows

```
template <typename T, double T::* ... Ms>
struct MyClass
 { /* something */ };
```

To take the correct values in `set()` you can make somethings as follows

```
void set (T const & v0)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { 0, (var.emplace_back(v0.*Ms), 0) ... };
 }
```

Observe that, to simplify, I've changed your `var` vector in a vector of `double`s, not of pointers to `đouble`s.

The following is a full (simplified) example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct MyData
 { double x, y ,z; };

template <typename T, double T::* ... Ms>
struct MyStruct
 { 
   std::vector<double> var;

   void set (T const & v0)
    {
      using unused = int[];

      (void)unused { 0, (var.emplace_back(v0.*Ms), 0) ... };
    }
 };

int main ()
 {
   MyData md { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };

   MyStruct<MyData, &MyData::y, &MyData::x>  ms;

   ms.set(md);

   for ( auto const & d : ms.var )
      std::cout << d << ' ';

   std::cout << std::endl;

 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much max. This is the approach I was looking for

Comment: I implemented my solution this way and works perfectly. However, it fails with nested structs (e.g.  &MyData::data::x). Is there any way to generalize this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to have the user specify a tuple and indexes:

```
struct MyData : std::tuple<double, double, double> {
    enum Names { X, Y, Z }; // Named indexes.
};

template<class T, size_t... Indexes>
class MyClass {
    std::vector<double*> var;
public:
    void set(T const& t) {
        auto unused = { (*var[Indexes] = std::get<Indexes>(t), 1)... };
        static_cast<void>(unused);
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass<MyData, MyData::X, MyData::Y> myobj;
    MyData mydata;
    myobj.set(mydata);
}
```